# How is it possible to instantiate a CellList<String> object using a TextCell object as parameter for CellList<String> constructor?

Tags: java, gwt, celllist

This how the code looks like in the GWT Javadoc mini tutorial:

```
TextCell textCell = new TextCell();
CellList<String> cellList = new CellList<String>(textCell);
```

I ask this because I can’t see any relationship between TextCell and it relationship with the CellList constructor requirements, therefore, I cant see how textCell satisfies CelList requierments.

The CellList constructors are:

```
CellList(Cell<T> cell)
Construct a new CellList.
CellList(Cell<T> cell, CellList.Resources resources)
Construct a new CellList with the specified CellList.Resources.
CellList(Cell<T> cell, CellList.Resources resources, ProvidesKey<T> keyProvider)
Construct a new CellList with the specified CellList.Resources and key provider.
CellList(Cell<T> cell, ProvidesKey<T> keyProvider)
Construct a new CellList with the specified key provider.
```

My question aims to basically understand how this works, and if you guys can tell me which Java or OOP topic or something could explain this in detail.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the relation between `TextCell` and `Cell`? What doubt do you have with the first constructor?

Comment: Is TextCell extends Cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextCell` simply implements `Cell<String>`: http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/TextCell.html

Comment: but it says "Cell.Context", what does it mean?

Comment: There's a class `Context` defined inside the `Cell` interface. And because `TextCell` implements `Cell`, it inherits the nested class. The thing you want to look at is at the top of the page: _“All Implemented Interfaces: `Cell<java.lang.String>`”_